# How to move a bitmap slowly on the window by Direct2D?

Tags: c++, winapi, direct2d

I am making a game by Direct2D and I need some help. In this game, I need to move a bitmap on the window slowly and rotates. However, when I ran the code, the bitmap didn't show on the window, if I wait a moment, it shows. I don't know how to deal with the problem because if it sleeps after it moves, the game suspended animation. And this is the following code:

```
VOID Rotate()
{
    ID2D1BitmapBrush* pBitmapBrush = NULL;
    g_pRenderTarget->CreateBitmapBrush(g_pMainRole, &pBitmapBrush);
    pBitmapBrush->SetExtendModeX(D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_CLAMP);
    pBitmapBrush->SetExtendModeY(D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_CLAMP);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps = { 0 };
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(g_hGameWnd, &ps);
    g_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

    DOUBLE dCurrentX = 0;
    UINT uCurrentAngle = 0;
    RECT rc = { 0 };
    GetClientRect(g_hGameWnd, &rc);

    while (dCurrentX <= rc.right - 128)
    {
        pBitmapBrush->SetTransform(
            D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(uCurrentAngle % 360, D2D1::Point2F(64, 64)) *
            D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Translation(D2D1::SizeF(dCurrentX, 60))
        );
        g_pRenderTarget->DrawBitmap(g_pBgBitmap, D2D1::RectF(0, 0, 
            g_pRenderTarget->GetSize().width, g_pRenderTarget->GetSize().height));
        D2D1_RECT_F rc = D2D1::RectF(350, 150, 1200, 700);
        g_pRenderTarget->DrawRoundedRectangle(D2D1::RoundedRect(rc, 10, 10), g_pBrush, 10.0F);

        if (pBitmapBrush != NULL)
        {
            g_pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(D2D1::RectF(dCurrentX, 60, 1920, 1080), pBitmapBrush);
        }
        pBitmapBrush->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());
        dCurrentX += 0.1;
        uCurrentAngle++;
        // Sleep(10);
        // This code makes my game suspend animation.
    }
    g_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    EndPaint(g_hGameWnd, &ps);

    SafeRelease(pBitmapBrush);  // This is my inline function
    // It calls pBitmapBrush->Release() if pBitmapBrush is not null.
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's the `EndDraw()` call that presents the graphics, but you never get there until after breaking out of the `while`-loop (which is presumably your animation implementation). Please see [this introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/learn-to-program-for-windows) to learn how a graphical Windows program is structured.

Comment: It works! However, when the program is painting, it got stuck and then there was a message box: "`game.exe` is not responding". But if I ran it with debugger or I switched to another window, the message box didn't show. I've tried to put `Rotate` into another thread and call `WaitForSingleObject(hPainterThread, INFINITE)`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: I searched on the Internet and I knew that I can avoid that by setting the caption, but this game is full-screened, and I don't know how to set it as well.

Comment: The system shows the *"\<program\> is not responding"* dialog box whenever the thread owning the window isn't dispatching messages for an extended period of time. You're going to have to learn how Windows programs work. Until that has been addressed, there's no reason to hope to make any forward progress. A [book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X/) is highly recommended.

Comment: Do you mean that the child thread has to send a message (e.g. `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`) to the thread owning the window, and then give up its time slice in order to let the thread owning the window to dispatch the message?

Comment: There is no message sending across threads involved here. GUI's are inherently single-threaded, hence the necessity to constantly dispatch messages. You cannot just keep spinning in your `WM_PAINT` handler indefinitely. This is explained in the book I linked to previously. You cannot make forward progress until you understand the application model.

Comment: And now I solve it. I added `SleepEx(0, FALSE)` in order to let Windows recalculate each thread's priority.

Comment: Throwing threads at a problem you haven't understood isn't going to be part of the solution. Making a problem go away and solving a problem are entirely different things.

Comment: I'm trying my best to understanding this problem with many ways, but not only to buy this book.